# QPrinter When click button my program crashes Why?

Tags: qt, printing, qprinter

When i click the button, the program crashes. I will post my code:

```
void Test1::on_pushButton_1_clicked() // print the information
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setCreator("Me");
    printer.setDocName("Print");
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);

    QPrintPreviewDialog *pd = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer);

    connect(pd,SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)),this,SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));

    pd->exec();
}



void Test1::print(QPrinter *p)
{
    QPainter painter(p);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);

    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing |
                           QPainter::TextAntialiasing |
                           QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);

    painter.drawText(100, 100, "Name: ");
    painter.drawText(300, 100, "SuperMan");
}
```

Please show me where is my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is "QPrintPreviewDialog *pd = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer);" located in your code?

Comment: Its declared in the button_clicked function as we can see.  What do you mean actually? I am not very good with the pointers yet. QPrintPreviewDialog *pd = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer); is only there, where you see it. I haven't used it anywhere else

Comment: in your code it looks as if it is outside

Comment: Can you paste your whole code as is? Also, could you please send the backtrace? Which operation system are you using, which Qt version, etc?

Comment: This is the whole code, everything else is Proxy Models, ListModels. My main target is to get value from TableView cell. I get the value, and then i put it in the drawText Function. When i press the button, my PrintPreview is showing up, there is no problem, but when i click on the print button in it, then my program crashes. As you see in my  post code in the drawText i've used some ready string "SuperMan", and the program crashes again. I thought that, that may be the problem. But is not. There is nothing more about this, that that you see in the post. This is everything. Thanks again

Comment: You said that the creation of the dialog is insided the "clicked" method. But as we can see it is obviously outside of the body of the method.

Comment: Ops, sorry for that. I can't handle stackoverflow code insertion yet. I 've edited it now. My code is ok with that. The mistake was only here

Comment: My Qt is version 2.7.0 Based on Qt Version 5.0.2. My operation system is Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. The preview was shown with the text and I could print it. You could try to debug the print-method in the qt sources (`QPrintPreviewDialogPrivate::_q_print()`).

Comment: Maybe i forgot to say that this code does not work in my big program. But it is working in my experimental projects. My big program contains lot of classes and parents and my experimental has only one class. Can there be a problem with the inheritance of the parents and the childs (this).... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your answers, finally i've solved my problem.So how did i solved it? I've just changed Release mode to Debug mode. Tadaaam. Thats it. The file is a bit more bigger, but who cares. Everything works excellent. Thanks a lot for your answers again.