# Qt PrintPreviewDialog , When click Print button, program crashes Why?

Tags: qt, printing

I've got the following code:

```
void Test1::on_pushButton_1_clicked() // print the information
{
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setCreator("Me");
printer.setDocName("Print");
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);

QPrintPreviewDialog *pd = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer);

connect(pd,SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)),this,SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));

pd->exec();
}



void Test1::print(QPrinter *p)
{
QPainter painter(p);
painter.setPen(Qt::blue);

painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing |
                       QPainter::TextAntialiasing |
                       QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);

painter.drawText(100, 100, "Name: ");
painter.drawText(300, 100, "SuperMan");
}
```

It works in my experimental projects, which are with 1 class [ 1 dialog ] only, but in my main project, when i press the button, the preview starts successfully, but then when i do press the "Print" button, my program just crash. It says "Your program stopped working, windows will search for solution" or something like that.
I need to say that my program has a lot of classes and dialogs.
I am almost sure that there is a problem with the pointers.
I don't have lot of experience, so i just can't find where my mistake is.
Please look my code and tell me what should i do because i've got only 2 more days to finish that project.
Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: add some `qDebug()`s and see where it crashes. or just run in a debugger

Comment: possible duplicate of [QPrinter When click button my program crashes Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752218/qprinter-when-click-button-my-program-crashes-why)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that you create your printer object in the stack

```
[..]
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
[..]
```

and pass the pointer to it to the print preview dialog. As soon as dialog is running with `exec()` your printer object still alive, however when you close the dialog, you exit from `Test1::on_pushButton_1_clicked()` function, so the printer object got destroyed. Further reference to it leads to crash.
As a solution try to create your printer from heap like:

```
void Test1::on_pushButton_1_clicked() // print the information
{
    // This printer should be deleted later.
    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer->setCreator("Me");
    printer->setDocName("Print");
    printer->setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);

    QPrintPreviewDialog *pd = new QPrintPreviewDialog(printer);
    connect(pd, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)), this, SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));

    pd->exec();
}
```

Comment: vahancho, your answer was the best to now, but it is crashing again, the only change i've done is to make the printer like this:    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution); First i declared it with pointer in the header file QPrinter *printer, and then just: printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution), maybe i can't understand you what do you want me to do. I can't remove the pointer from the QPrintPreviewDialog cause i can't use SIGNALS. Please tell me what to do. If you want copy my code from my post, and reedit it. Thanks again

Comment: @user2521257, I have modified my response and included the implementation that I think should solve the crash. Please try that out again.

Comment: Vahancho, thanks again, but this is not working again. I tried with Release, Debug, and the Debugger, but i've got the crash again. With the debugger i get big assembler error with the following message: "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operation System. Signal name: ?, Signal meaning: Unknown signal "

Comment: @user2521257, does it crash when you click on "print" button only, or any other button in preview dialog? For example "Page Setup" button. Hm, actually, I cannot reproduce this issue on my test application.

Comment: I tested every button in the preview dialog, but it is crashing only on the "Print button", the big question is why this code is not crashing on my experimental projects, it is crashing only on this big project. I have to do something, i 've got 3 days to solve that problem. Month later i will go to programming race with that project. If you have some other ideas write them, however, thank you a lot for your all help

Comment: @user2521257, when I hit the "Print" button, the system (Windows) print dialog appears. It looks fine, and I see the list of installed printers. Is it possible, that your system has a failed printers configuration? Did you try to print something from other applications?

Comment: Yes, as i said, my test applications are working good with this print code. Only my big project is making problems

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, finally i've solved my problem.So how did i solved it? I've just changed Release mode to Debug mode. Tadaaam. Thats it. The file is a bit more bigger, but who cares. Everything works excellent. Thanks a lot for your answers again.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the flow of this program and you'll see why it doesn't work.

1. You make a printer on the **stack** and then connect signals to it.
2. Print dialog is shown, allowing the user to do whatever to it.
3. An external event, like a **print** button is pushed, closing the Print Dialog and destroying your printer on the stack because it went out of scope.
4. The `print` slot now has invalid memory space where the `QPrinter*` used to be and crashes your whole program.

In Qt, most everything should be allocated on the heap for exactly this reason.

Comment: Tyler, i tried everything, just everything, with vahancho's  code, with your tips, and the only thing i get is crash. As i said to vahancho i get big assembler error. This is part of it:         Function: RaiseException
0x75a6d35b  <+0x0040>         les    -0x18(%eax),%edx
0x75a6d35e  <+0x0043>         adcb   $0x8d,0xcc483ff(%edi,%edi,8)
0x75a6d366  <+0x004b>         inc    %ebp
0x75a6d367  <+0x004c>         mov    $0x50,%al
0x75a6d369  <+0x004e>         call   *0x75a6115c
0x75a6d36f  <+0x0054>         leave

Comment: I'm guessing that the crash is elsewhere, then.

Comment: Tyler, with heap, do you mean the beggining of the cpp file. After the includes?. Please give me example.Thanks

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, finally i've solved my problem.So how did i solved it? I've just changed Release mode to Debug mode. Tadaaam. Thats it. The file is a bit more bigger, but who cares. Everything works excellent. Thanks a lot for your answers again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your answers, finally i've solved my problem.So how did i solved it? I've just changed Release mode to Debug mode. Tadaaam. Thats it. The file is a bit more bigger, but who cares. Everything works excellent. Thanks a lot for your answers again.